# Iterating a list of tasks to get the translators that can perform the translation in python

Tags: python, list

```
l1 = [('x', [1]), ('y', [1]) ('z', [2]]
l2 = ['1', '2', '3']
```

Desired output, assuming that '1' can be done by 'x' and 'y', and 'z' can do '2':

```
l3 = [[['1'['x', 'y']], ['2'['z']], ['3'[]]
```

So then i can do an untie between 'x' and 'y' using aditional paramenters that for the sake of redability i wont be putting here unless asked.

This is what i've come to so far:

```
x = []
for i in l2:
    for j in l1:
        if i in j[1][0]:
              x.append(j[0])
```

This gives me the possible l1, but i'm having no luck in adding the l2 part in a way i can put 'x' and 'y' toghether. Since this a school project, i can't use tools like zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a `dict` with the keys being the elements of `l2`, initializing their values as a list, then iterate over `l1` elements appending `element[0]` to the list of the key that matches `element[1]`.

```
l3 = {}
for elem in l2:
    l3[elem] = []

# Look for matches in l1
for letter, tasks in l2:
    for task in tasks:
        l3[str(task)].append(letter)
```

In this algorithm, `l3` will be a `dict` instead of `list` which makes it easier to access the values in each task. If you really need to be a `list`, just convert it to one.

Comment: Thanks got it to work with a few modifications thati'll post here if you want, thanks alot again